# Why do the female imps in the DCAU look like human women and not like the male imps? Is this the case in the comics as well?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, mister-mxyzptlk, superman-the-animated-series

As shown in the following clip from the DCAU show *Superman: The Animated Series* (1996–2000), the female imp looks very much like how a typical human woman in the DCAU would look, as opposed to being very short and cartoonish in appearance like Mr. Mxyzptlk.

[image: female imp in Superman: The Animated Series]

Is there any explanation for this? Is this how it is in the comics as well?

Comment: She's also the only woman we encounter, as far as I remember, which leaves the question as to whether or not they're all like that.

Comment: rule of funny? Also, women were always hot in 1940s to 1980s cartoons on which mr mxyzpltlk comic and character was based., while men had all sorts of shapes  Read more here: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SexyDimorphism (warning, tvtropes link!)

Comment: @Clockwork - We see other female imps in the comics. They look basically human.

Comment: [NSFW] https://www.oglaf.com/dimorphism/

Answer (score 13):

This appears to be a perfect example of a phenomenon known as [*Flanderization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanderization);

> ...the process through which a complex fictional character's essential traits are oversimplified to the point where they constitute their entire personality, or at least exaggerated while other traits remain, over the course of a serial work

Gizpy (AKA Gspie, AKA Ms. Gsptlsnz) started out in the comics as essentially a female version of Mister Mxyzptlk, a short, but recognisably human-like entity.
Gsptlsnz is portrayed as his bossy girlfriend, again short and relatively ugly.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[**Superman's Pal, Jimmy Olsen #52** (1961)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman%27s_Pal,_Jimmy_Olsen_Vol_1_52)</sup></sub>

> [image]
> <sub><sup>**[DC Comics Presents #97](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/DC_Comics_Presents_Vol_1_97)** (1986)</sup></sub>

Over time Mxyzptlk became dramatically [more gnomelike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riwjVGffS0g) and Gsptlsnz became more overlty feminine.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[**JLA #31** (1999)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/JLA_Vol_1_31)</sup></sub>

Until they eventually just started writing her as a sexbomb.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[**Countdown to Final Crisis #22**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Countdown_to_Final_Crisis_Vol_1_22) (2007)</sup></sub>

> [image]
> <sub><sup>**[Superman Adventures 26](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Adventures_Vol_1_26)** (2016)</sup></sub>

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[[**Superman Reborn**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman:_Reborn) (2017)</sup></sub>

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[**Action Comics 1000** (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Comics_1000)</sup></sub>

Comment: It looks like all the examples at the bottom came after the _[Superman TAS (1996-2000)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_The_Animated_Series)_ series. I feel like the cartoon might have inspired that change.

Comment: @Clockwork - I've not seen the show, so I can't really comment, but yes, this does appear to be a case of the tail wagging the dog.

Comment: https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Gsptlsnz She looked like she was inspired by Jessica Rabbit

Comment: @Clockwork - My thoughts exactly.

Comment: This says *what* is happening, but it doesn't answer *why*.

Answer (score 11):

Just to complete Valorum's answer

In [Superman v1 #335](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_335) (1979) we can find [Miss Bgbznz](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Miss_Bgbznz_(Earth-One))

> [image: Mxyzptlk's wedding]
> <sub><sup>[**Superman v1 #335** (1979)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_335)</sup></sub>
> Yes, strange are the ways of love... And stranger still... In a strange land...
> **Priest:** ... I now pronounce you *imp* and *wife*!
> **Bgbznz:** Oh, Mxy, darling... I know how much you love a good joke-- ***giggle*** So here's one you'll *adore*!  I figured you'd *never* marry me if you saw what I *really* looked like... ...So I *magically projected the image of me you proposed* to! But now that we're hitched-- I can show you my *real* self: *this!*
> **Mxyzptlk:** *Yaaaah!* Now... *That's not funny!*
> **Someone from the crowd:** *Mxyzptlk* may have *attoned* for his *misdeeds*-- But he *still* hasn't learned what's *funny* and what's *isn't!* -- Or else he'd *appreciate* the fact that his wife's joke is... a veritable *work of art! Ha ha ha!*

Close-up

[image: Miss Bgbznz close-up]

Her more-human-like form was a trick for luring Mxyzptlk. According to her profile they got divorced later.

Comment: An excellent find. This strongly suggests that he sexy exterior is a glamour, rather than real

Comment: @Valorum I read that comic when I was a child, long time ago. :-)

Comment: Hmm. So perhaps the later (hotter) forms we see are just her projected images?

Comment: @T.E.D. Well, according to Alan Moore's story [Whatever Happened to the Man of Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Whatever_Happened_to_the_Man_of_Tomorrow%3F) the funny little man image is also a [facade](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Mister_Mxyzptlk_(Earth-423))

Answer (score 3):

Valorum does a good job of explaining the time-line of the imp women turning from female imps into pin-up models.

As for the why, it helps illustrate just how much Superman is living rent-free in Mr. Mxyzptlk's head; he's so obsessed that he is not noticing the charms of someone who would prefer that he give it up and (as is said in one case) spend time with her.

Comment: This raises up the fact that people from the 5th dimension can change their appearance at will (which is something she did in Superman TAS to try to entice Mxyzptlk; she also got turned into a coconut tree too). Still, it makes you wonder if there is a reason she remains that way forever, even when he's not there.

Comment: Why does she have a perfect body? Because she can.